# Linux Mint 19 Tara logs out unexpectedly or clossing apps

Tags: linux-mint, logout

I am having problems with Linux. Randomly, it logs off and closes all my apps.
At other times, it also shuts down some apps without logging me out.
Can you help me?

```
Specs:
Linux Mint 19 Tara
16gb RAM
GTX 1050ti
i5-7400
```

The video drivers were recently updated to see if it would work, but it did not work.